# Dynamically adding and refreshing elements to the Accordion widget in jQuery UI

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

[Several](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008243/jquery-ui-accordion-adding-rows-without-destroying-and-recreating) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5927365/jquery-accordion-with-dynamic-content) here on SO reference this [open jQuery UI feature request](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/4672) for the ability to dynamically add/remove panels from the Accordion widget. The ticket itself is marked (closed feature: fixed) and  from what I can tell from the [unit tests](https://github.com/petersendidit/jquery-ui/blob/3dd2ef0f367c7423f9f3d2e4faf71f0a7287c716/tests/unit/accordion/accordion_methods.js) and a pull from their Git repository it appears to be implemented in the latest release.

However if I try to add a div like they did in the unit test above:

```
var element = $("#accordion");
$("#accordion").append("<h3>3</h3><div>3</div>");
$("#accordion").accordion("refresh");
```

I can't get it to work.

However [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008243/jquery-ui-accordion-adding-rows-without-destroying-and-recreating) works:

```
$("#accordion").append("<h3>sec</h3<div>test</div>").accordion("destroy").accordion();
```

But I don't want to "destroy" the accordion, I just want to append (or prepend) an element and refresh it.

Looking at the div I added in Chrome's inspector shows that the element I added doesn't have the same CSS styling added as the rest of the accordion:

[image]

Comment: after you add it.. like in the example in the link - you have to destroy and reinitialize the accordian for it to work... since the newly added elements were not there at the time of accordion initialization.

Comment: Thanks, Jack, you asked exactly the same question I have in mind when trying to resolve the same problem. ;) And I agree with you -- destroying and re-creating accordion doesn't look good.

Answer (score 36):

unibasil is correct that jQuery UI 1.10.0 has updated the [refresh](http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#method-refresh) method to now allow this behavior.

Here's the 1.10.0 [changelog](http://jqueryui.com/upgrade-guide/1.10/#added-ability-to-add-remove-panels) note about the update.

> The refresh method will now recognize panels that have been added or
>   removed. This brings accordion in line with tabs and other widgets
>   that parse the markup to find changes.

**Setup**

```
<div class="questions">
    <div>
        <h3><a href="#">Question 1. My First Question ?</a></h3>
        <div>
            First content<br />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <button id="addAccordion">Add Accordion</button>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$('#addAccordion').click( function() {
    var newDiv = "<div><h3>Q2 New Question</h3><div>New Content</div></div>";
    $('.questions').append(newDiv)
    $('.questions').accordion("refresh");        
});
```

**Example**

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a6rCu/57/)** showing that you can add new accordions on the fly without having to destroy the old one.

Comment: This helped me to good extent in implementing sortable/drag-gable for dynamic sections.

Comment: @Jarek - In jsFiddle you shared, is there any way to stop 1st tab/panel from getting open after adding question dynamically? Each time we add question, it causes 1st tab to open. I dont want this behavior. All panels should be in collapsed/closed state. Any thoughts/ideas?

Comment: This is old, but to answer @Chetan since I also wanted that behavior, use the [active](http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#option-active) option by adding .accordion("options", "active", 2) <-- where 2 represents the zero-based index of the panel to open

Comment: On every refresh() method the first accordion keep open. IS there any solution for this?

Answer (score 7):

Thanks to [Jarek](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13868192/dynamically-adding-and-refreshing-elements-to-the-accordion-widget-in-jquery-ui/14487304#14487304)!
In my case is it functional without enclosing div. The div causes creating next accordion.

```
$('#addAccordion').click( function() {
  var newDiv = "<h3>Q2 New Question</h3><div>New Content</div>";
  $('.questions').append(newDiv)
  $('.questions').accordion("refresh");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually discussed behaviour was included in jQuery UI 1.10.0 (just [released](http://jqueryui.com/)) and works fine for me.