# jQuery UI Accordion - does refresh method overwrites initialisation settings?

Tags: jquery-ui, refresh, accordion

Currently I am working on a project for which I use the jQuery UI Accordion.
Therefore I initialise the accordion on an element by doing

```
<div id="accordion"></div>

$('#accordion').accordion({
    collapsible: true,
    active: false,
    heightStyle: "content"
});
```

After init the accordion I append some data coming from an AJAX request. (depends on user interaction)

In a simplified [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6jRSc/2/) - which does exact the same thing as the ajax call - you can see how this looks like.
So far it seems to be working quite well but there is one problem I face.
In my initialisation I say that I want all panels to be closed but after calling refresh on the accordion everything of those settings seems to be gone and one panel opens.

Note that I implemented jQuery UI v1.10.2 in my fiddle. [Update notes](http://jqueryui.com/upgrade-guide/1.10/#accordion) say

> The refresh method will now recognize panels that have been added or removed. This brings accordion in line with tabs and other widgets that parse the markup to find changes.

Well it does but why has it to "overwrite" the settings I defined for this accordion?
I also thought about the possibility that it might be wrong to create the accordion on an empty `<div>` so I tested it with a given entry and added some elements afterwards.
But the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6jRSc/3/) shows exactly the same results.

In a recent [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14487304/2240272) I found someone who basically does the same thing as I do but in his [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a6rCu/57/) he faces the same "issue".
He adds a new panel and the first panel opens after the refresh.

My current solution for this issue is to destroy the accordion and recreate it each time there's new content for it.
But this seems quite rough to me and I thought the refresh method solves the need to destroy the accordion each time new content gets applied.
See the last [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6jRSc/7/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    //variable to show "new" content gets appended correctly
    var foo = 1;
    $('#clickMe').on('click', function () {
        var data = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            data += '<h3>title' + foo + '</h3><div>content</div>';
            foo++;
        }

        if ($('#accordion').hasClass('ui-accordion')) {
            $('#accordion').accordion('destroy');
        }
        $('#accordion').empty().append(data).accordion({
            collapsible: true,
            active: false,
            heightStyle: "content"
        });
    });
});
```

Unfortunately it is not an option for me to change the content of the given 3 entries because the amount of panels varies.

So my questions are the one in the title and if this behaviour is wanted like that or if anybody faces the same problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the explanation of this behaviour, have a look in the refresh() method of the jquery-ui accordion widget, the problem you are facing is at line 10 :

```
refresh: function() {
    var options = this.options;
    this._processPanels();
    // was collapsed or no panel
    if ((options.active === false && options.collapsible === true) || !this.headers.length) {
        options.active = false;
        this.active = $();
    // active false only when collapsible is true
    } if (options.active === false) {
        this._activate(0); // <-- YOUR PROBLEM IS HERE
    // was active, but active panel is gone
    } else if (this.active.length && !$.contains(this.element[0], this.active[0])) {
        // all remaining panel are disabled
        if (this.headers.length === this.headers.find(".ui-state-disabled").length) {
            options.active = false;
            this.active = $();
        // activate previous panel
        } else {
            this._activate(Math.max(0, options.active - 1));
        }
    // was active, active panel still exists
    } else {
        // make sure active index is correct
        options.active = this.headers.index(this.active);
    }
    this._destroyIcons();
    this._refresh();
}
```

Comment: I see...could you explain what `this._activate(0);` means? Does it set the collapsible to false and therefore active false can't work anymore? I don't understand why it behaves like that when it checks if active is false and collapsible true....and then changes those settings O.o

Comment: `this._activate(0);` activates the first panel of the accordion. The collapsible option is not modified (as you can see in your jsfiddle you can still collapse all the panel). I don't see the logical behind this too. One thing you can do is to change the activate option after refresh with `.accordion('option', {active:false})` but you will see the panel closing animation...

Comment: Your explanation makes sense the implementation...well...not really O.o Yes I tried to set active to false after refresh but this looks really ugly ^^

Comment: Hmm but it's not a bug, or is it? I mean it seems not logical to me but I dont know if one could call it bug. On the other side there's nothing I could really do to fix this or?

Comment: I found a ticket, seems like it is a bug. http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/9189 But they are working on it

Comment: Yep, this is a bug :), the bug is in fixed state, and the fix will be available in the [1.10.3 version](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/milestone/1.10.3) which should be available tomorrow \o/

Comment: I'll just accept your answer because you pointed me to the right direction. Had never thought about looking in the source code. Thanks!